# Facing issue while trying to connect to spring websockets from flutter to receive broadcasted messages

Tags: spring, websocket, flutter

I have tried following the code snippet provided in flutter.io cookbook(https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/web-sockets/)  to connect to websockets.

It was working well for the test server "echo.websocket.org" provided in the code but same is not getting connected when trying with custom websocket server written in Spring. I have tried with multiple websockets which are working in other projects, even sample test websocket is also not getting connected.

Please help to resolve the issue or suggest steps to take to achieve successful connectivity to websockets.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: i was also facing the same problem but it solved when i started using ws on nodejs. Socket.io didn't work for me

Comment: Did you write ws in nodejs?

Comment: yes i am using NodeJs

Comment: Ok. NodeJS socket got connected from flutter websocket. My main concern is that  my server code is in spring websockets which I need to get connected from flutter.

Comment: Hi, did you ended up finding a solution? I am having the same problem and cannot get a connection

Comment: I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @sri Hi. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution for that.